# Linq Reverse -does it leave the variable changed or make a copy

Tags: c#, linq, reverse

I have a dicionary of strings and dates

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, DateTime>
```

as a private member variable in a class

I have methods which recursively get the next and previous value in the dictionary given a particular key

e.g.
It takes the given key, does a database lookup, if that is null, it gets the next one and so on recursively. It does this both forward and backwards

I have used this to get the next one
[Find next record in a set: LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333709/find-next-record-in-a-set-linq)

My question is can I simply add Reverse to the linq statement to do this backwards?

Obviously it will work but I am worried about the state it will leave my member variable list in

i.e. will it be reversed? or is a copy have made when doing the reverse?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Enumerable.Reverse` does not mutate the sequence on which it is invoked.

Comment: so the member variable will remain in it's original order? i.e. not reversed?

Comment: @Christo Fur: Correct. (Also, this is something that you can trivially test yourself.)

Comment: @Christo, used normally, LINQ will not mutate original collections or objects within them, but will filter/project/group/order sequences to allow you to work intuitively with the data structures in your code.

Comment: very true. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, Enumerable.Reverse will not change the underlying sequence (except in the rare case where enumerating over the sequence will change it).

However, be warned that if you are using a List, you might end up calling List.Reverse, which DOES change the list.

```
List<int> list = /* initialize */;
IEnumerable<int> asEnumerable = list;

// these call List<int>.Reverse(), which changes the list
list.Reverse();
((List<int>)asEnumerable).Reverse();

// these call Enumerable.Reverse<int>(), which does not change the list, but returns a new IEnumerable<int>
asEnumerable.Reverse();
((IEnumerable<int>)list).Reverse();
((IList<int>)list).Reverse();
```

Sorry, I would have made this a comment on one of the other correct answers, but I wanted to include code.

Comment: Is this also true for `IList<T>` ?

Comment: @MeirionHughes No, because the IList<T> interface does not require a Reverse method.  Therefore Enumerable.Reverse will be called.

Answer (score 1):

None of the Linq methods, including Reverse, will alter the enumerable that is passed to them, UNLESS enumerating the enumerable causes alterations (you'd know if this were the case; few if any built-in Enumerable types have side effects to data access).

What reverse likely DOES do, since it requires knowledge of the cardinality of the collection, is to slurp the enumerable's elements into an array which it will iterate in reverse. A lot of oft-used Enumerable Linq methods, such as OrderBy, do this behind the scenes.